# AutoMapper 8 ConvertUsing(Complex,string)

Tags: c#, automapper, valueconverter

I am trying to clean a string `EmailInstructions` during a mapping but it fails when I call `Mapper.Configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();`  with:

`No coercion operator is defined between types 'System.String' and 'ElectionViewModel'`

**Here's my setup:**

```
public class AutoMapperConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.AddProfile<SystemProfile>();
        });

        Mapper.Configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    }
}
```

**My Mapper:**

```
public class SystemProfile : Profile
{
    public SystemProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<ElectionViewModel, Election>()
            .ForMember(x => x.EmailInstructions, y => 
               y.ConvertUsing(new EmailInstructionVariablesCleanerConverter()))
```

**My ValueConverter**

```
public class EmailInstructionVariablesCleanerConverter : IValueConverter<ElectionViewModel, string>
{
    public string Convert(ElectionViewModel source, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return CleanVariables(source.EmailInstructions);

    }
    private static string CleanVariables(string text)
    {
        return Clean the text here
    }
}
```

Comment: See [this](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Value-converters.html), but maybe value transformers or value resolvers are a better fit here.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to solve a similar error but I have discovered the cause of yours along the way. I offer my observations here by filling in some missing details to assist others who still may be confused.

You didn't include your source and destination classes. Because of AutoMapper's behavior and the error you reported, I assumed that your destination type `Election` includes at least the following member:

```
public class Election
{
    public string EmailInstructions { get; set; }
}
```

When you created your mapping for that member using the map expression

```
CreateMap<ElectionViewModel, Election>()
    .ForMember(x => x.EmailInstructions, y => y.ConvertUsing(new EmailInstructionVariablesCleanerConverter()))
```

AutoMapper matched the destination and source `EmailInstructions` members, then selected your source string `EmailInstructions` to pass to `EmailInstructionVariablesCleanerConverter`, which was defined to expect an `ElectionViewModel` type as the source object. Because there was no conversion operator defined on either type that would implement coercion from a `string` into the required `ElectionViewModel` object, the expression compiler threw the "no coercion operator" exception.

Given those details, @Lucian made the suggestion that you replace your converter to something more appropriate: a value transformer to modify your source string; or, a value converter to convert the source string into a new string.